# Is ES Fuzzy Query Symmetric

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

Is Elastic Search [Fuzzy Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) symmetric?

For example if I have:

```
Setup1
Index Documents = ["hat", "funny"]
Queries = ["cat", "bat", "monkey"]
```

What if I reversed it to be:

```
Setup2
Index Documents = ["cat", "bat", "monkey"]
Queries = ["hat", "funny"]
```

Is it guranneted that

```
X = Setup1.FuzzyQuery(Y)
Y = Setup2.FuzzyQuery(X)
```

For example if in Setup1

```
Query "cat" will result in ["hat"] 
Query "bat" will result in ["hat"]
```

Is it guranteed that in Setup2

```
Query "hat" will result in ["cat", bat"]
```

searched online and checked ElasticSearch documentaion but found nothing

Comment: What is X and Y in your example?

Comment: @imotov they simply represent the input and output.
For example if in Setup1
Query "cat" will result in ["hat"]
Query "bat" will result in ["hat"]

Is it guranteed that in Setup2
Query "hat" will result in ["cat", bat"]

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that. Elasticsearch data consists of documents and fields. I have not idea what is what in your example. Could your express your example in form of elasticsearch mapping and elasticsearch data?